# Powershell get-websitestate cmdlet not working at Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

I created the following script to check the website status and the IIS instance status. When I manually runs it from PowerShell ISE with Adminstrator, it works fine but when I triggered from Task Scheduler, it just didn’t worked!  And it was due to GET-WEBSITESTATE as this cmdlet required to run from PS ISE Administrator.
My question, what is the command need to setup in Task Scheduler?
Currently, i setup the task schedule with the following:
Program/Script: Powershell.exe
Add arguments:  powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file "D:\PS\CheckPMRWebpage\Code\Monitor PMR webpage 6-1.ps1

```
## The URI list to test 
$URLListFile = "D:\PS\CheckPavcapWebpage\Code\PavCapurlList.DAT"  
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$Result = @() 

  Foreach($Uri in $URLList) { 
  $time = try{ 
  $request = $null 
   ## Request the URI, and measure how long the response took. 
  $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri } 
  $result1.TotalMilliseconds 
  }  
  catch 
  { 
   <# If the request generated an exception (i.e.: 500 server 
   error or 404 not found), we can pull the status code from the 
   Exception.Response property #> 
   $request = $_.Exception.Response 
   $time = -1 
  } 
  #   $lStatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode
  # if ($lStatusCode -eq 401){
  #  $linfo = "The site is ok."
  # }

  $result += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
  Time = Get-Date; 
  Uri = $uri; 
  StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode; 
  StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription; 
  ResponseLength = $request.RawContentLength; 
  TimeTaken =  $time;   
  } 
} 

##################################################
#Prepare body in HTML format for URL
##################################################

if($result -ne $null) 
{ 
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE>PMR Website Availability Report</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> PavCap Website Availability Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B>StatusCode</B></TD><TD><B>StatusDescription</B></TD><TD><B>Additional Info</B></TD><TD><B>ResponseLength</B></TD><TD><B>TimeTaken</B></TD></TR>" 
    Foreach($Entry in $Result) 
    { 
        if($Entry.StatusCode -eq "200") 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=lightgreen>" 
            $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center></TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>" 
        } 
        elseif($Entry.StatusCode -eq "401") 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=yellow>" #<TD></TD><TD align=center></TD><TD align=center></TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.AddInfo)</TD><TD align=center></TD><TD align=center></TD></TR>" 
            $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>Website is up but it failed on Authentication!</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>" 
            #AddInfo = "Site is ok as it failed on Authentication"
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
            $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>Website is not up - please check!</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>" 
            #AddInfo = "red"
        } 
        #$Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.AddInfo)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>" 
    } 
    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
} 

$Outputreport | out-file D:\PS\CheckPavcapWebpage\siteavailabilityrpt.html
#Invoke-Expression D:\PS\CheckWebpage_and_IIS\siteavailabilityrpt.html

######################################
# The Instances Name list to check
######################################
 $InsNameFile = "D:\PS\CheckPavcapWebpage\Code\PavCapInsName.dat"  
 $InsList = Get-Content $InsNameFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
 $Result1 = @()

  Foreach($Ins in $InsList){

   $InsNameState = (Get-WebsiteState -Name $Ins).value

  $result1 += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
  #Time = Get-Date; 
  InsName = $ins; 
  InsStatus = $InsNameState; 
  } 
} 

##################################################
#Prepare body in HTML format for Instance
##################################################

 if($result1 -ne $null) 
{ 
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE>PMR Website Availability Report</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> PavCap Instance Availability Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>Instance Name</B></TD><TD><B>InsStatus</B></TD></TR>" 
    Foreach($Entry1 in $Result1) 
    { 
        if($Entry1.InsStatus -eq "Started") 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=lightgreen>" 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
        } 
        $Outputreport += "<TD align=center>$($Entry1.InsName)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry1.InsStatus)</TD></TR>" 
    } 

    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
    $Outputreport +="<footer><p>This is a system generated email, please do not reply to this email, thank you.  For time being, the email addresses are controlling from the script until solution found.</p></footer>"
} 
 $Outputreport | out-file D:\PS\CheckPavcapWebpage\siteavailabilityrpt.html -Append
$htmlfilename = "D:\PS\CheckPavcapWebpage\siteavailabilityrpt.html"

############################################################################
## Email to users (hardcoding email address on the top of scirpt - declare
###########################################################################

$htmlbodyreport = Get-Content "$htmlfilename" -Raw
Send-MailMessage -to $lrecipients -from $lsender -Subject $lemailsubject  -BodyAsHtml -body $htmlbodyreport  -SmtpServer "abc.bab.cbb.com"
```

Comment: You should check the box for "Run with highest privileges" when creating the Scheduled Task in the General tab of the tasks properties. If you are creating the scheduled task with powershell (using the *-ScheduledTask* cmdlets) then you should use `-RunLevel Highest` when registering your scheduled task using Register-ScheduledTask. Please specify how you are creating the scheduled task.

Comment: I did checked the "Run with highest privileges" box and the action completed with return code 2147942401.  

From TASK SCHEDULE, select Create Task.
In General tab, check Run whether user is logged or not and check do not store password.  Check Run with highest privileges.
In Triggers tab, specify weekly and specific timing.
In Actions tab, Action - Start a program, Program/Script - as mentioned on my original post, Add arguments - as mentioned on my original post.
In Condition tab, check Start the task only if computer is on AC power, check Stop if the computer switches....